# Two Way Meeting Workspace Sync between Outlook and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, outlook, meeting-workspace

Currently, if a meeting is created in Outlook and linked to a Sharepoint 2010 Meeting Space, the meeting is created but the Sharepoint calendar is not updated.

Conversely, if a meeting is created in Sharepoint, and attendees added, they are not notified with a meeting request and entry in their calendar.

Is there any way to ensure that, whichever method is used to create a meeting, that both Sharepoint and Outlook are in sync with each other?